# Product status changed after clicking "place order in magento

Tags: magento

I hope someone can help me out.

I want : The product isn't taken out of stock until the payment transaction is complete.

Suppose I have one product and someone(customer) is checkout this product but before payment transaction process this product taken 'out of stock'.

Answer (score 0):

I would try turning off the Magento stock management functionality (System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory).  Then you can write an extension that listens for the **sales_order_invoice_save_after** event and adjust stock quantities yourself.  You'll also want to handle returns/credit memos using the same type of event observer code.  Keep in mind, however, that if you get 2 orders for the same item and you only have 1 in stock you'll end up in a backorder scenario.  As long as you're okay with that, this should work.